# Must declare the scalar variable in a dynamic query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got a stored procedure that takes two xml parameter, which I would like to use as my filters for the data in the stored procedure. I am using a dynamic query to process the nodes from the XML.

The results I am getting is :

> Must declare the scalar variable "@RegionXML".
> Must declare the scalar variable "@oXml".'

Here is my query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Proc_MyStored_Procedure]
    @OrgUnitXml varchar(max),
    @RegXml varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    DECLARE @FinalSet nvarchar(max) ,          
            @WhereClause varchar(800),
            @oXml xml = @OrgUnitXml,
            @RegionXML xml

    SET @RegionXML = CASE
                         WHEN @RegXml = '' 
                             THEN '<Data><Rec><Id>0</Id></Rec></Data>'
                             ELSE @RegXml
                     END

    IF (@RegXml <> '')
        SET @WhereClause = ' and  r.RegionId in (  select nref.value(''Id[1]'', ''bigint'') as RegionId
        from @RegionXML.nodes(''//Data/Rec'') as R(nref)  )   and OrgUnitId in(select nref.value(''Id[1]'', ''int'') as OrgUnitId
        from @oXml.nodes(''//Data/Rec'') as R(nref))';
    ELSE
        SET @WhereClause = ' and OrgUnitId in(select nref.value(''Id[1]'', ''int'') as OrgUnitId
        from @oXml.nodes(''//Data/Rec'') as R(nref))';

    BEGIN
        --- My dynamic query is here

 set @FinalSet = 'Select  EmployeeId,CompanyId,[FullName], EmailAddress, Org AS [Department], CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) as [ReportDate],MAX(pv.Allowance) AS [Allowance], MAX(PV.[Annual Gross]) AS [AnnualGross],
Max(pv.Bonus) As [Bonus],Max(pv.Commission) As [Commission],Max(pv.[Medical - Contribution]) As [MedicalContribution], Max(pv.[Medical Employer Deductions]) As [MedicalEmployerDeductions], Max(pv.Other) As [Other], Max(pv.Overtime) As [Overtime], Max(pv.Pension) As [Pension], Max(pv.[Standby Allowance]) As [StandbyAllowance]
    
from
(
    select st.SalaryTypeId, st.CompanyId, st.SalaryTypeName as SalaryTypeName ,es.SalaryAmount,es.EmployeeId, + emp.FirstName + '' '' + emp.MiddleName + '' ''+  emp.LastName as [FullName], emp.EmailAddress , cs.Org,es.DateCreated
    from  SalaryType as st 
          left outer join (select EmployeeSalaryId, EmployeeId, SalaryTypeId, SalaryAmount, Active,DateCreated
                            from EmployeeSalary where Active = 1 ) as es
    on st.SalaryTypeId = es.SalaryTypeId    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Employee AS emp on es.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId

    LEFT OUTER JOIN    CS AS cs on emp.OrgUnitId = cs.ID

    INNER JOIN Region as r on st.CompanyId = r.CompanyId
        where st.CompanyId = '  + cast(@CompanyId as varchar(100)) + 'and st.Active = 1   and es.Active = 1  ' + @WhereClause+ '
) as q
Pivot(
  AVG(SalaryAmount)
  for SalaryTypeName in(    [Allowance],
                            [Annual Gross],
                            [Bonus],
                            [Commission],
                            [Medical - Contribution],
                            [Medical Employer Deductions],
                            [Monthly Gross],
                            [Monthly Net],
                            [Other],
                            [Overtime],
                            [Pension],
                            [Standby Allowance])
) as pv
where EmployeeId is not null
GROUP BY EmployeeId,CompanyId,[FullName],EmailAddress,Org 
Order by [FullName]';                

execute(@FinalSet)
        EXECUTE (@FinalSet)
    END
END
```

Comment: the `@FinalSet` is empty, you didn't assigned anything to that variable at all. How is it you are getting that error message

Comment: @Squirrel for this type of issue it is OK to post without the implementation detail, because it is irrelevant and keeps the discussion focussed, but OP should have put more effort into explaining this to us. Some dynamic query builders get quite complex, the _building of the string_ can be distracting, especially if we see potential optimisations, we need to focus on just the error that OP describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message suggests, you need to declare the variables *inside* the dynamic script if you are going to use `EXEC` or `EXECUTE`.

```
    --- My dynamic query is here
    set @FinalSet = '
DECLARE @RegionXML varchar(max) = ''' + + ''';
DECLARE @oXml varchar(max) = ''' + + ''';
Select  EmployeeId,CompanyId,[FullName], EmailAddress, Org AS [Department], CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) as [ReportDate],MAX(pv.Allowance) AS [Allowance], MAX(PV.[Annual Gross]) AS [AnnualGross],
...'
    ...

    EXECUTE (@FinalSet)
```

You could also use the [`sp_executesql` stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as it allows a simpler syntax to pass in external parameters without having to embed the parameter values within the script:

```
    --- My dynamic query is here
    ... build @FinalSet ...

    DECLARE @params nvarchar(max) = '@RegionXML varchar(max), @oXml varchar(max)';
    EXEC sp_executesql @FinalSet, @params, @RegionXML, @oXml
```

The only caveat to this is that the script (`@FinalSet` ) and the parameter declarations (`@params`) *MUST* be `of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.`

The full result looks like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [Proc_MyStored_Procedure]
    @OrgUnitXml varchar(max),
    @RegXml varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    DECLARE @FinalSet nvarchar(max) ,          
            @WhereClause varchar(800),
            @oXml xml = @OrgUnitXml,
            @RegionXML xml

    SET @RegionXML = CASE
                         WHEN @RegXml = '' 
                             THEN '<Data><Rec><Id>0</Id></Rec></Data>'
                             ELSE @RegXml
                     END

    IF (@RegXml <> '')
        SET @WhereClause = ' and  r.RegionId in (  select nref.value(''Id[1]'', ''bigint'') as RegionId
        from @RegionXML.nodes(''//Data/Rec'') as R(nref)  )   and OrgUnitId in(select nref.value(''Id[1]'', ''int'') as OrgUnitId
        from @oXml.nodes(''//Data/Rec'') as R(nref))';
    ELSE
        SET @WhereClause = ' and OrgUnitId in(select nref.value(''Id[1]'', ''int'') as OrgUnitId
        from @oXml.nodes(''//Data/Rec'') as R(nref))';

    BEGIN
        --- My dynamic query is here

 set @FinalSet = 'Select  EmployeeId,CompanyId,[FullName], EmailAddress, Org AS [Department], CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) as [ReportDate],MAX(pv.Allowance) AS [Allowance], MAX(PV.[Annual Gross]) AS [AnnualGross],
Max(pv.Bonus) As [Bonus],Max(pv.Commission) As [Commission],Max(pv.[Medical - Contribution]) As [MedicalContribution], Max(pv.[Medical Employer Deductions]) As [MedicalEmployerDeductions], Max(pv.Other) As [Other], Max(pv.Overtime) As [Overtime], Max(pv.Pension) As [Pension], Max(pv.[Standby Allowance]) As [StandbyAllowance]
    
from
(
    select st.SalaryTypeId, st.CompanyId, st.SalaryTypeName as SalaryTypeName ,es.SalaryAmount,es.EmployeeId, + emp.FirstName + '' '' + emp.MiddleName + '' ''+  emp.LastName as [FullName], emp.EmailAddress , cs.Org,es.DateCreated
    from  SalaryType as st 
          left outer join (select EmployeeSalaryId, EmployeeId, SalaryTypeId, SalaryAmount, Active,DateCreated
                            from EmployeeSalary where Active = 1 ) as es
    on st.SalaryTypeId = es.SalaryTypeId    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Employee AS emp on es.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId

    LEFT OUTER JOIN    CS AS cs on emp.OrgUnitId = cs.ID

    INNER JOIN Region as r on st.CompanyId = r.CompanyId
        where st.CompanyId = '  + cast(@CompanyId as varchar(100)) + 'and st.Active = 1   and es.Active = 1  ' + @WhereClause+ '
) as q
Pivot(
  AVG(SalaryAmount)
  for SalaryTypeName in(    [Allowance],
                            [Annual Gross],
                            [Bonus],
                            [Commission],
                            [Medical - Contribution],
                            [Medical Employer Deductions],
                            [Monthly Gross],
                            [Monthly Net],
                            [Other],
                            [Overtime],
                            [Pension],
                            [Standby Allowance])
) as pv
where EmployeeId is not null
GROUP BY EmployeeId,CompanyId,[FullName],EmailAddress,Org 
Order by [FullName]';                

        DECLARE @params nvarchar(max) = '@RegionXML varchar(max), @oXml varchar(max)';
        EXEC sp_executesql @FinalSet, @params, @RegionXML, @oXml

    END
END
```

You have actually done well here to parameterise the dynamic script and to isolate the parameter initialization. This should provide a good balance for SQL Server to optimize the execution plans. For more information on dynamic SQL my favourite reference is [SQLShack: Working with parameters in the sp_executesql stored procedure](https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-parameters-in-the-sp_executesql-stored-procedure/)